# GLSL - list of changed pixels when drawing a line on a texture

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

How can I use GLSL (along with OpenGL 4.3+) to figure out which pixels in an image will change color when I draw a line over it?

Explanation. I have an image (texture) of size 600x500 for example. I want to draw a polyline (aka glLineStrip) on top of this texture without antialiasing (the polyline is set in some coordinates (from 2 to 10 on the X axis, for example)), and find out which pixels on the texture should be changed. The output to the screen is completely unnecessary.

P.S. I want to do it on GPU, because there are a lot of polylines and the image size can reach 5000x5000.

P.P.S. If possible, I would like to get a "conservative rasterization", i.e. a result where all pixels under the line are painted, no matter how much the line crosses the pixel.

Comment: Not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do but you might want to look at using a [stencil buffer](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Stencil-testing).

Comment: Draw white lines to a perfectly black framebuffer, then read the resulting buffer back to memory and look for non-black pixels?

Comment: Also doesn't "without antialiasing" conflict with "conservative rasterization"? Without AA your pixel only gets touched if the line goes through the center (iirc).

Comment: @Botje: It's usually not required that a line goes through the center of a pixel to be color even without antialiasing. What happens is that the closer pixel gets colored fully opaque while with antialiasing all surrounding pixels are painted semitransparent.